# Visualizing data between two dates with telerik:DateTimeCategoricalAxis

Tags: c#, wcf, telerik

I'm currently using the bar series and `telerik:DateTimeCategoricalAxis` to represent data. I have grouped data into weekly and trying to present them between the start date of the week and end date of the week. In other words, I'd like the bar series to be appeared between the two dates (i.e. start of the week & end of the week) as opposed to only one date.

But I was only able to show the label for one particular date (only the start date of the week). Here is what I've done so far.

```
<telerik:DateTimeCategoricalAxis
                                            x:Name="datetimeAxis"                                            
                                        LabelFitMode="MultiLine"
                                        LabelFormat="{Binding Tab.CurrentPoC.LabelFormat}"
                                        LabelInterval="1"
                                        LabelOffset="0"
                                        LabelRotationAngle="270"
                                        LabelStyle="{DynamicResource LabelStyle}"
                                        LastLabelVisibility="Visible"
                                        LineDashArray="1 1"
                                        LineStroke="{DynamicResource CouleurTexte}"
                                        LineThickness="1"
                                        MajorTickInterval="1"
                                        MajorTickLength="1"
                                        PlotMode="OnTicks"
                                        SmartLabelsMode="SmartStep"
                                        TickThickness="5"
                                        ZIndex="0" Height="5" />
```

Answer (score 1):

RadChartView has two DateTime Dedicated axes, the first one is DateTimeCategoricalAxis, the other is DateTimeContinuousAxis. These axes are different in nature as one is categorical(discrete), and the other is continuous.
I suggest you attempt DateTimeContinuousAxis control.
Please refer to the below document.
https://docs.telerik.com/devtools/wpf/controls/radchartview/axes/datetimeaxes
Wish you good luck.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Abraham's answer. You can use `DateTimeContinuousAxis` instead of `DateTimeCategoricalAxis`, but note that the continuous one doesn't have the `MajorTickInterval` property. Instead, you can use `MajorStep` and `MajorStepUnit`.

Here is an example:

```
<telerik:RadCartesianChart.HorizontalAxis>
    <telerik:DateTimeContinuousAxis MajorStepUnit="Day" MajorStep="1" />
</telerik:RadCartesianChart.HorizontalAxis>
```